# How can I change indentation of one section only

Tags: indentation

**Problem description**

I would like to have a different indentation for my Literature section.

Right now it looks like this:[image]

**Edit: My MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english, slovene]{babel}     
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{fontspec}           
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}   
\usepackage{setspace}          
\singlespacing

% Nastavitve strani
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=30mm,
 top=30mm,
 right=30mm,
 bottom=30mm,
 marginparwidth=0mm,
 }

\begin{document}
\sloppy 

\section{Other section's style}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla volutpat congue justo, at hendrerit metus dictum sed. Nulla facilisi. 

Suspendisse pretium metus quis purus volutpat aliquam. Integer pellentesque nec mi tempus fermentum. Integer fermentum quam ac nulla euismod, et commodo turpis condimentum. Praesent eu tempor sem. Quisque tristique felis sapien, in scelerisque velit varius euismod. 

Fusce est orci, pellentesque at ex vel, vestibulum luctus risus. Etiam nec dictum ante, et tincidunt enim. Vestibulum vulputate porta leo. Maecenas rutrum turpis a imperdiet luctus. Nunc pretium nibh nec neque iaculis ultrices. Maecenas id malesuada felis. Nullam id mauris eget felis rhoncus tempor. Phasellus quis cursus massa, eget facilisis purus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras rutrum, neque quis laoreet sodales, ligula diam tempor diam, ac viverra velit elit ac risus.

\section{Literatura}
\noindent Vu, T., Hu, B., Munkhdalai, T. in Yu, H. (2018). Sentence simplification with memory-augmented neural networks. \emph{Proceedings of the 2018 Conference of the North American Chapter of the Association for Computational Linguistics: Human Language Technologies, Volume 2 (Short Papers)} (str. 97-85)

\noindent Xu, W., Napoles, C., Pavlick, E., Chen, Q. in Callison-Burch, C. (2016). Optimizing statistical machine translation for text simplification. \emph{Transactions of the Association for Computational Linguistics, 4}, 401-415.


\end{document}
```

I would like the references to be listed in a way that if one reference extends to more than one row its indentation changes as shown in the image below: [image]
Other sections should not be affected.

Edit: I'm using APA citation style.

Comment: Might be a good idea to show code you have currently.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. There are a lot of possible [styles for bibtex](https://www.bibtex.com/bibliography-styles/), and many more to [biblatex](https://pt.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Biblatex_citation_styles). We don't know which style you are using. It seems you want something like [apa](https://www.bibtex.com/s/bibliography-style-misc-apa/) but not exactly the same, at least for articles: Surname1, A.B. <and in your language> Surname2, C.D. (YYYY). Title. Journal. NN(X): pg begin-pg end.

Comment: You could adjust \lefskip and \rightskiip, unless you are inside a list environment.  You might also look at the quotation environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't recommend doing the references manually, but that's your choice.

You can use hanging indentation.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english, slovene]{babel}     
\usepackage{fontspec}           

% Nastavitve strani
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
% total={170mm,257mm}, % either this or all margins
 left=30mm,
 top=30mm,
 right=30mm,
 bottom=30mm,
 marginparwidth=0mm,
}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\newcommand{\litem}{%
  \par
  \addvspace{\smallskipamount}
  \hangindent=1em
  \noindent\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\section{Other section's style}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla volutpat 
congue justo, at hendrerit metus dictum sed. Nulla facilisi. 

Suspendisse pretium metus quis purus volutpat aliquam. Integer pellentesque 
nec mi tempus fermentum. Integer fermentum quam ac nulla euismod, et commodo 
turpis condimentum. Praesent eu tempor sem. Quisque tristique felis sapien, 
in scelerisque velit varius euismod. 

Fusce est orci, pellentesque at ex vel, vestibulum luctus risus. Etiam nec 
dictum ante, et tincidunt enim. Vestibulum vulputate porta leo. Maecenas 
rutrum turpis a imperdiet luctus. Nunc pretium nibh nec neque iaculis 
ultrices. Maecenas id malesuada felis. Nullam id mauris eget felis rhoncus 
tempor. Phasellus quis cursus massa, eget facilisis purus. Pellentesque 
habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis 
egestas. Cras rutrum, neque quis laoreet sodales, ligula diam tempor diam, 
ac viverra velit elit ac risus.

\section{Literatura}

\litem Vu, T., Hu, B., Munkhdalai, T. in Yu, H. (2018). 
  Sentence simplification with memory-augmented neural networks.
  \emph{Proceedings of the 2018 Conference of the North American Chapter of 
  the Association for Computational Linguistics: Human Language Technologies, 
  Volume 2 (Short Papers)} (str. 97-85)

\litem Xu, W., Napoles, C., Pavlick, E., Chen, Q. in Callison-Burch, C. (2016).
  Optimizing statistical machine translation for text simplification.
  \emph{Transactions of the Association for Computational Linguistics, 4}, 401-415.

\end{document}
```

A few things to note:

1. you're overspecifying `geometry` parameters, I left the 3cm margins.
2. `inputenc` should not be used with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.
3. I added a small vertical space between bibliography items.

[image]

Comment: What is your change in code?

Comment: @sabinagorenc Sorry, I pasted the wrong code. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed :) I should use the .bib file from the beginning but at this stage I am satisfied with what I have.